# Распараллеливание цикла с помощью OpenMP

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, openmp

Подскажите, #pragma omp parallel for в этом коде поможет ли ускорить производительность и не приведёт ли это к ошибкам? Правильно ли я понимаю что эта директива позволит рандомить элементы используя производительность нескольких ядер?

Код для генерации рандомного расположения элементов.

```
 #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        double f = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
        double random_x = r_min.x + f * (r_max.x - r_min.x);
        f = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
        double random_y = r_min.y + f * (r_max.y - r_min.y);
        
        #pragma omp critical
        cout << "Coordinates " << i+1 << " element: " << random_x << " " << random_y << "\n";
        
        element[i].x = random_x;
        element[i].y = random_y;
    }
```

Результат распараллеливания:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему не всегда работает cout вывода?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *"поможет ли ускорить производительность и не приведёт ли это к ошибкам"* - запустите, померяйте, сообщите о результатах. `(double)rand()` явно не сулит ничего хорошего.

Comment: Для начала стоит выяснить, что за функция `rand` используется. Что у нее с потокобезопасностью.

Comment: функция rand потокобезопасна @user207200

Comment: для `cout <<`, то лучше ещё один цикл сделать, после и убрать  #pragma omp critical

Comment: В таком случае дело за малым - приступайте к бенчмаркингу! Только вот вместо внесения в `critical` секцию лучше будет удалить вывод из цикла, если уж речь идет о повышении производительности.

Comment: @user207200 да, конечно, спасибо, это и вправду лишнее

Comment: Эксперимент на VC++2022 показывает, что получается быстрее. Вопрос только в потокобезопасности `rand()`.

Comment: 1) Эта штука `#pragma omp critical` заставляет потоки синхронизироваться, причём на каждой итерации цикла, что негативно сказывается на производительности. Если есть возможность, то следует избегать лишних синхронизаций потоков. 2) По стандарту функция `rand` не обязана быть потокобезопасной ([c.math.rand](http://eel.is/c++draft/c.math.rand#3)), поэтому в общем случае поведение приведённого кода может быть не определено. 3) В C runtime library от Microsoft функция `rand` потокобезопасна, причём каждый поток хранит собственный экземпляр внутреннего состояния генератора псевдослучайных чисел.

Comment: Так что здесь распараллеливание вызовов `rand` должно ускорить процесс генерации, но каждый поток должен самостоятельно инициализировать внутреннее состояние генератора вызовом `srand`, иначе разные потоки будут генерировать одинаковые последовательности псевдослучайных чисел. 4) В glibc функция `rand` также потокобезопасна, но использует общее внутреннее состояние для всех потоков. Следовательно здесь вызов `rand` будет заставлять потоки синхронизироваться, что будет вносить негативный вклад в производительность.

Comment: 5) В общем, распараллеливание вызовов `rand` может как привести к ускорению, так и нет, как приводить к ошибкам, так и нет. Нужно смотреть, как функция реализована и проводить тесты. 6) Или вообще отказаться от `rand` в пользу генераторов из заголовочного файла [<random>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random). Пусть каждый поток заведёт себе какой-нибудь собственный не зависящий от других потоков генератор, например `std::mt19937`, и спокойно генерирует случайные числа.